# Login credentials for the Tapkey API

Tags: credentials, tapkey

How can I generate the login credentials for the Tapkey API? The new security system provider who installed the locks and set up the Tapkey App doesn't know how to do it. Our booking system needs those credentials. Example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYR9C.png)

I logged in as admin in the Tapkey App but couldn't find it.

Comment: Consider your keys compromised. Your partial censoring is insufficient to protect those values.

Comment: No problem. Those are not the real once.

Answer (score 0):

> Consider your keys compromised. Your partial censoring is insufficient to protect those values.

Please consider ceejayoz's advice and change the credentials.

As you mentioned that you are trying to use a third-party booking system, this is currently hard to answer, as the response might depend on the booking system.

Which booking system do you use? Does it offer a Tapkey integration? Is there any documentation available on how to connect it with Tapkey?

Comment: The booking system is wy.by and does offer a Tapkey integration. I just now got the answer that create client credentials in portal.tapkey.io which I will try now. Once I have the credentials, the setup can be completed.